# Loading an item from a collection inside a collection LINQ Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

While developing an application in `ASP.NET CORE` I encountered the following problem:

I have a `DBSet<UserHistory>`. What I need to do is to access the element Sessions inside UserHistory. Then I need to access the last element in Jobs inside from the session element.

Ideally I would like to load just one element without loading all collection.

I tried the following and it does not work:

...

```
var item = userHistory.Where(n=>Name == name).Include(s=>s.Sessions).Last().
    ThenInclude(j=>j.Jobs).Last();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
public class UserHistory
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public List<SessionHistory> Sessions { get; set; }


    public UserHistory()
    {

    }
}


public class SessionHistory
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime ClockIn { get; set; }
    public DateTime ClockOut { get; set; }

    public List<JobHistory> Jobs { get; set; }


    // The flaged must be set when the user clocks out
    public bool IsClockedOut { get; set; }

    public SessionHistory()
    {
        Jobs = new List<JobHistory>();
    }
}

public class JobHistory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public int JobNumber { get; set; }
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }

    public DateTime JobStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime JobFinish { get; set; }


    // Will be set to true when signed out of the job
    // Use it to determain if the the user is signed out!
    public bool IsJobComplete{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `Include` only includes entire collections (when applied to collection navigation properties, of course). No sorting or filtering involved. You have to write a LINQ query that gets the desired results in a `Select ` statement.

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

this part `(n=>Name == name)` should be `(n=>n.Name == name)`, shouldn't it?

Then try something like:

`var item = userHistory.Where(n=>n.Name == name).First().Sessions.Last().Jobs.Last();`